# Таймер для выключения компьютеров на Python 3

Tags: python

Нужен простой скрипт для выключения компьютеров, чтобы когда компьютер включался он проверял время и начал отсчет до конкретного времени и отключился.

Comment: Зачем для этого Python? Хватит написать bat'ник в пару строк и запихать в автозапуск.

Comment: наверно можно и на powershell  это организовать ......

Answer (score 2):

Например это можно сделать бесконечным циклом, который будет проверять текущее время с желаемым

```
import os
import time

def shutdown(offPC=19):
    while time.gmtime().tm_hour < offPC:
        time.sleep(60)  # ожидание 1 минуту
    os.system("shutdown -s")
```

Также можно попробовать после включения запускать скрипт, вычислять время в секундах до желаемого времени отключения и формировать такую запись(отложенное выключение):

```
os.system("shutdown -s -t xx")
```

Где `XX` время в секундах до отключения.